# How to get rid of error "could not convert string to float"?

Tags: python, pandas, testing, linear-regression, training-data

Currently trying to test my model with the rest 30% of the data and to show the test results, but can't seem to be able to test it

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_training_data, x_test_data, y_training_data, y_test_data = train_test_split(x_data, y_data, test_size = 0.3)

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
MLmodel = LinearRegression()

MLmodel.fit(x_training_data, y_training_data)
pd.DataFrame(MLmodel.coef_, x.columns, columns = ['Coeff'])
```

Comment: To better help you, please provide the error you are getting along with what line it is erroring on and what the data looks like.

Comment: Hi, this is the error I'm getting ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'MARCH'  -- and it's showing by MLmodel

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you have *at least* one column that need to be encoded as numerical with [`factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html).

I made the example below to show you the general logic (*based on your inputs*) :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "gender": ["Male", "Female", "Male", "Female"],
    "age": [25, 32, 47, 19],
    "income": [50000, 75000, 100000, 30000],
    "location": ["New York", "Los Angeles", "Chicago", "Houston"],
    "sales": [100, 200, 300, 400]
})
    
df[["gender", "location"]] = (df[["gender", "location"]]
                                .apply(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0])) # <-- add this line

x, y = df.drop("sales", axis=1), df["sales"]

x_training_data, x_test_data, y_training_data, y_test_data = train_test_split(x_data, y_data, test_size=0.3)

MLmodel = LinearRegression()
MLmodel.fit(x_training_data, y_training_data)

df = pd.DataFrame(MLmodel.coef_, x.columns, columns=["Coeff"])
```

Output :

```
print(df)

LinearRegression
LinearRegression()
                 Coeff
gender    2.040816e-08
age      -5.714285e-07
income   -1.428571e-03
location  2.040816e-08
```

Comment: thank you! do you possibly have discord so chat a bit further?

Comment: I do not have discord but you can ask anything you want here ;)

Comment: I wanted to try to share a pic of my assignment but can't attach files here

Answer (score 1):

## Categorical Data Encoding

Most machine learning models only accept numerical data eg : floats, integers, etc. They don't accept strings or any other data formats as input. So you have to *encode* your data from your initial data format/representation to numerical representation.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np

MLmodel = LinearRegression()

x_data = pd.DataFrame({
  "gender": ["Male", "Female", "Male", "Female"],
  "income": ["50000", "75000", "100000", "30000"],
  "location": ["New York", "Los Angeles", "Chicago", "Houston"],
  "sales": [100, 200, 300, 400]
})

y_data = [0, 1, 0, 1]

x_training_data, x_test_data, y_training_data, y_test_data = train_test_split(x_data, y_data, test_size = 0.3)

MLmodel.fit(x_training_data, y_training_data)
pd.DataFrame(MLmodel.coef_, x_data.columns, columns = ['Coeff'])
```

This will give you a similar error because your columns "gender", "income", "location" are not represented numerically which is required for Linear models.

### Label Encoding

There are several ways to encode your data, the simplest one is called "Label encoding", you represent each category from your variable as a number. For example in the gender variable, we can use 0 to represent Male and 1 to represent female. Similarly for location, "New York" will be represented by 0, Los Angeles by 1, "Chicago" by 2, "Houston" by 3. Then your dataframe would look like this :

```
x_data = pd.DataFrame({
  "gender": [0, 1, 0, 1],
  "income": ["50000", "75000", "100000", "30000"],
  "location": [0, 1, 2, 3],
  "sales": [100, 200, 300, 400]
})

y_data = [0, 1, 0, 1]

x_data["income"]=x_data["income"].astype(np.int32)
x_training_data, x_test_data, y_training_data, y_test_data = train_test_split(x_data, y_data, test_size = 0.3)

MLmodel.fit(x_training_data, y_training_data)
pd.DataFrame(MLmodel.coef_, x_data.columns, columns = ['Coeff'])
```

You should also be careful of the variable datatype, for example income is a numerical variable, but it's represented as a string in our dataframe. you can use x_data.dtypes to see the datatype for each variable / column

```
x_data.dtypes
```

Will output this :

```
gender      int64
income      int32
location    int64
sales       int64
dtype: object
```

### One Hot encoding

However this isn't always the best way to encode your data, because it assumes an ordinal relationships between your categories ( 3 is bigger than 0) but it doesn't make sense for certail categorical features). One way to counter this is by using "One hot encoding"

```
x_data_new = pd.get_dummies(x_data)
x_data_new
```

Now your x_data_new looks like this :

| index | sales | gender_Female | gender_Male | income_100000 | income_30000 | income_50000 | income_75000 | location_Chicago | location_Houston | location_Los Angeles | location_New York |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 100 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |  |
| 1 | 200 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |  |
| 2 | 300 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  |
| 3 | 400 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |  |

Again this only works for certain use cases, imagine you have a variable / column with thousands or millions of categories, it'll cause your input data to have a large number of rows. Which is why there's other encoding types for this specific type (frequency encoding, target encoding, etc)